# Inserting 8 or more objects into array crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Simple question,

I loop thru my table view cells and add the objects to an array:

```
NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [self.ammoTable numberOfSections]; ++j) // loop thru sections
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.ammoTable numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)//in each section loop thru the cells
    {
        [cells addObject:[self.ammoTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
    }       
}
```

This works PERFECT, as long as the table view has only 7 or less cells, if i add 8 or more, the app crashes with this log to the console:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: @Woot4Moo when i add breakpoints, it shows the line `[cells addObject...` as throwing the error

Comment: Why are you adding your cells to an array? This seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @rdelmar because i have to loop through the cells to see which ones are displaying certain information.

Comment: This is what your data model is for. Cells only display data. Scan your data model, not the cells.

Comment: -1 for not identifying the failing line (as indicated by the error message).

Comment: You misunderstand how UITableView works.  Back up and study it a bit.  "Cells" are like blank pieces of slate that the app writes on when they're added at one end of the scroll, and when they're pushed off the other end they're erased and recycled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableView` returns `nil` if the index path refers to a cell that is currently not visible, therefore

```
[cells addObject:[self.ammoTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
```

crashes in that case.

Comment: Okay, i get what you mean, but i need to add all of the cells whether they are visible or not, so how could i do that if it doesnt allow a nil object to be added?

Comment: Change your design, @KurtMoyer, and have this code ask either a controller/delegate or data source/model rather than the view, for the information it needs.

Comment: @KurtMoyer: It could work if you call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of the table view data source. - But can you explain what you are trying to achieve? It generally looks like a design error to me.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, and yeah. I basically need to loop through all of the cells (which are loaded using core data) and see which ones are displaying certain information. So this seemed as the most logical way to achieve this. Add cells to array, & loop through the array. May i ask if you have an easier/more logical way of doing this?

Comment: @KurtMoyer: As others have already said in the comments: Use the data source or model. For example, if you have a fetched results controller, you can loop over the `fetchedObjects` array.

Answer (score 1):

it lead to crash because you have only seven rows at the screen, when it all added to array after that it returns nil. for solving what you can do is create a method which take input as indexpath and returns cell object without using reuse cell.

Answer (score 0):

The magic is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. For certain values this is returning `nil`. Check this method and fix it.